# Sitecore how to edit an Items's Standard Field Value

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.5

In Sitecore I have an Item. Lets say its name is `weekDay`. It has a default field (Standard Fields) `Sortorder`. I want to edit this field and put a string inside it. But following code give me `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

```cs
switch (weekDay.Name.ToLower())
{
    case "monday":
        weekDay.Editing.BeginEdit();
        weekDay.Fields["Sortorder"].Value = "1";
        weekDay.Editing.EndEdit();
        break;
}
```

I am getting exception on this line `weekDay.Fields["Sortorder"].Value = "1";`in above code.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ok. The only issue is that the field is not called `"Sortorder"`, it's called `"__Sortorder"`. Try:

```cs
weekDay.Fields["__Sortorder"].Value = "1";
```

Most of the Sitecore standard fields is prefixed with double underscore, e.g. `__Sortorder`, `__Hidden`, `__Display Name`, `__Read Only`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Most standard fields are prefixed with `__` (double underscore), so the field name is actually `"__Sortorder"`.

```cs
weekDay.Fields["__Sortorder"].Value = "1";

// Or use the field ID from Sitecore.FieldIDs class
weekDay.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.Sortorder].Value = "1";
```

The `Sitecore.FieldIDs` class contains the field ID of many, if not all, standard fields.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if weekDay is null ? I guess weekDay item is null

To edit an weekDay item you will have :

```
 if (weekDay!=null)
     {
    using (new EditContext(weekDay))  
     {  
        switch (weekDay.Name.ToLower())
                    {
                        case "monday":
                            weekDay.Fields["__Sortorder"].Value = "1";
                            break;
                     }
       }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer but the item is not null. I have tried to edit some other field (added by me) and I can access it without error.